# Does the presence of a kallah in shul during the week after the wedding exmpt the minyan from saying Tachanun?

Tags: halacha, wedding, tachanun

ArtScroll, among other Siddurim, lists in the instructions regarding *Tachanun* that the minyan does not recite it in the presence of a groom from the day of his wedding through the following week.

It specifically mentions the *groom's* presence. What if the bride is in the shul without the groom? Would the minyan also be exempt from reciting *Tachanun*? Is there any opinion that rules this way?